# Encoding problems with wordcloud and text mining

Tags: r, encoding, tm

I'm trying to implement a wordcloud of posts of a Facebook page, in Italian language. I'm able to develop the wordcloud well but I've problems in rendering particular characters typical of Italian such as à, è, ò etc. What I'd like is to encode all the text in UTF-8 in order to avoid these problem. Any suggestion?

Here's the code

```
new_variable <- as.vector(import_text)
#create corpus from vector of tweets
him_corpus <- Corpus (VectorSource(new_variable))
inspect(him_corpus[1])
him_clean <- tm_map(him_corpus, removePunctuation)
him_clean <- tm_map(him_clean, content_transformer(tolower))
him_clean <- tm_map(him_clean, removeWords, stopwords("italian"))
#him_clean <- tm_map(him_clean, removeNumbers)
him_clean <- tm_map(him_clean, stripWhitespace)
him_clean <- tm_map(him_clean, removeWords, c("skytg24", "sky")) #nserire qui l'hashtag oggetto di ricerca per esluderlo dalla cloud altrimenti altera i risultati
wordcloud(him_clean, ramdom.order=F, col=rainbow(50), max.words=70)
```

Comment: does adding `encoding = "UTF-8"` into `VectorSource()` work?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do (I work often with German text) is using the following cleaning function

```
SpecialCharacterCleaner <- function(text_vector){
  text_vector <- gsub("[ä]", "ae", text_vector)
  text_vector <- gsub("[ö]", "oe", text_vector)
  text_vector <- gsub("[ü]", "ue", text_vector)
  text_vector <- gsub("[è]", "e", text_vector)
  text_vector <- gsub("[é]", "e", text_vector)
  text_vector <- gsub("[à]", "a", text_vector)
  return(text_vector)
}
```

So you loose the accents (I know they are important, I am Italian), but you can do a clean analysis (difficulties may arise in the moment people use for the same word two different accents (by mistake) giving you actually two different words like "perchè" and "perché". That will alter your word count (believe me this happens a lot) and gives you multiple words that are actually the same.

But you can actually work with accents. I had the same problem with German language. So check the encoding of your file. My experience is that is not R that is a problem, but how your file is encoded. If you have a good editor (like Ultraedit for windows) you can check the encoding. If it is wrong, you will get strange characters instead of accents. I hope this helps you. You can find my short notes on text cleaning here https://udata.science/2017/06/02/string-cleaning-for-text-mining-in-r/ I hope it can help you (still a work in progress).

Regards, Umberto